# How do I test that a particular template was rendered in Sinatra or Padrino?

Tags: rspec, sinatra, padrino

Imagine you have two templates:

```
# app/views/users/foo.haml.html
%p ...

# app/views/users/bar.haml.html
%p ...
```

And a controller that renders these:

```
MyApp.controllers :users do
  get '/herp' do
    render 'users/foo'
  end
  get '/derp' do
    render 'users/bar'
  end
end
```

What's the best way to write an RSpec test that asserts that a particular view was rendered by a controller?

Ideally, is there a way to have the test check only that the view *would* have been rendered, without actually rendering it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Rack::Test`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-test) to check the rendering of the page:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
  # other stuff too…
end


describe "Getting the user's page", :type => :request do
  let(:username) { "herp" }
  before do
    get "/users/#{username}"
  end
  subject{ last_response }
  its(:status) { should == 200 }
  its(:body) { should include "Something that was on the template" }
end
```

Once that's working you could generalise it to generate different usernames to run the spec against and suchlike.

To check the page *would* have been rendered without rendering it, perhaps you could double the `render` method?

Comment: I don't want to make the test be a string match, because that's too brittle: If the view changes, the test should still work, since nothing in the controller was altered.

I guess it's possible to double on `render`, I hadn't thought of that. That's probably the best approach.

Comment: @JohnFeminella Well, the rendered output is a string, after all :) You may also want to run some kind of validity check on the template too, because without actually running it you won't know if a problem with the template would've caused an error in the renderer.

Comment: I agree that it's also a string match, but this string doesn't change when I edit the contents of the view. :)

Comment: @JohnFeminella My view is that sometimes a test needs to be tied to something specific, even if it introduces a brittleness, because that's just the way it is. I quite regularly introduce these kind of specs, you have to pay the piper somewhere :)